# what may cause unexpected log outs?

Tags: linux, login

Sometimes, my Linux PC unexpectedly closes my session (log out) while I am working, and puts me back the login window. If I have terminal 1 logged with root and 2 logged with another user (without X), these ones are not logged out. For example, for the last three hours, it has happened five times.

Other times, it leads to a reboot. So I have investigated:

- the UPS, but the behaviour is unchanged without it).
- the temperatures, but everything is fine (cpu, disks, video card).

I have started to investigate also:

- the memory (partially tested - I have to run a full testyt next night). EDIT: totally tested and passed.

My configuration is: Linux 2.6.37-tuxonice x86_64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7 CPU 860 @ 2.80GHz.

Any idea please?

Comment: you are not accidentally hitting a short-key, like alt+Q or so?

Comment: No, definitively not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have restored the last back-up of my system, and it works correctly again. I think the system was corrupted by a UPS failure along with an electrical brownout.